# Group Chat problem with Messages app

Tags: ios, messages, sms, group, chat

I have this problem whenever a group chat is created in Messages with me included. Any time somebody sends a text to the group, it sends it to me directly, but to everybody else it is shown in the group chat.

Because of this I get a bunch of random texts with no context from the people in the group chat. I can text to the group chat just fine, but whenever I receive texts they're not within the group.

**How do I troubleshoot/resolve this?**

Comment: A group chat _in which app_? Google Hangouts? Apple iMessage? Please be specific.

Comment: IMessage. I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think it's to do with what each participant in the group has set for "You can be reached for messages at:" I've had similar convos with my partner & sister & that was our eventual conclusion.

Comment: Elaborate?? I don't know what would be a problem with that or even where to reach it.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try going to Settings > Messages > Send & Receive. Under the "You can be reached by iMessage at" header, make sure your contact info is listed and checked i.e. the contact info at which your friends are trying to reach you.

I think this is what Tetsujin was suggesting in the comments.